# RXJS - call select only after dispatches are terminated

Tags: angular, rxjs

Im my app I have to dispatch many **actions**, to get data from rest services and save to the **Application State**.

```
store.dispatch(data1_action);
store.dispatch(data2_action);
store.dispatch(data3_action);
...
```

Then I have to call many **selectors**, and I have to pass data from the previous selector to the next one.

```
store.select(data1_selector)
  .pipe(
       switchMap(res1 => store.select(data2_selector, res1 )),
       switchMap(res2 => store.select(data3_selector, res2 ));
       ...
   );
```

The problem is that dispatch are asyncronous, so when I call, for example
`store.select(data2_selector, res1 )` that part of the state might be null because `store.dispatch(data2_action)` might be not executed yet.

What is the correct use of the operator in this scenario?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `filter` to ensure that the `null` values do not trigger then next operator in the pipe:

```js
store.select(data1_selector)
  .pipe(
    filter(res1 => !!res1),
    switchMap(res1 => store.select(data2_selector, res1)),
    filter(res2 => !!res2),
    switchMap(res2 => store.select(data3_selector, res2));
    filter(res3 => !!res3),
    ...
  );
```